# Get block id in block theme template

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I'd like to be able to print the block id/number of my custom block in its template. I feel like these must exist because Display Suite has a token for it: `[block_content:id]`.

Like a url to edit a block is, it goes to the edit form: `block/17`

How do I get that `17` in the twig template? Looking in [block.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21templates%21block.html.twig/8.2.x), I don't see anything about a block's number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find the `block_content` entity in the template variable `elements` to get the ID:

*block.html.twig:*

```
{{ elements.content['#block_content'].id() }}
```

Comment: For Drupal 9 it should be `{{elements['#id']}}`

Comment: @yunzen, the id in the top level of the block render element is more likely the id of the block itself, not of the block content entity the question is about.

Comment: yunzen's answer worked perfectly for me